# Recyclerview shows only 1 item

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

i'm facing a real strange problem, my recyclerview is showing only 1 item! I have tried multiple solutions seen on the net but none of them worked.

Here is my ListFragmentImmeuble.kt:

```
package com.example.mydata.fragments.list

import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.*
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.mydata.R
import com.example.mydata.viewmodel.EntrepriseViewModel
import com.example.mydata.viewmodel.ImmeubleViewModel
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_list_entreprise.view.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_list_immeuble.view.*

class ListFragmentImmeuble : Fragment() {

private lateinit var mImmeubleViewModel: ImmeubleViewModel

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_immeuble, container, false)

    val adapter = ListAdapterImmeuble()
    val recyclerView = view.recyclerView1
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())

    mImmeubleViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(ImmeubleViewModel::class.java)
    mImmeubleViewModel.readAllData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { immeuble ->
        adapter.setData(immeuble)
    })

    view.floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener{
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_listFragmentImmeuble_to_addFragmentImmeuble)
    }
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)

    return view
}
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.delete_menu, menu)
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    if (item.itemId==R.id.menu_delete){
        deleteAllImmeubles()
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}

private fun deleteAllImmeubles() {
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
    builder.setPositiveButton("Oui"){ _, _ ->
        mImmeubleViewModel.deleteAllImmeubles()
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Immeubles supprimés", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    builder.setNegativeButton("Non"){ _, _ ->
    }
    builder.setTitle("Supprimer la liste des immeubles? ")
    builder.setMessage("Êtes vous sure de supprimer toutes les immeubles?")
    builder.create().show()
}
}
```

and here is my ListAdapterImmeuble.kt:

```
package com.example.mydata.fragments.list

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.mydata.R
import com.example.mydata.model.Immeuble
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.custom_row.view.*


class ListAdapterImmeuble : RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapterImmeuble.MyViewHolder>(){

private var immeubleList = emptyList<Immeuble>()

class MyViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
    return MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.custom_row, 
parent, false))
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return immeubleList.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val currentItem = immeubleList[position]
    holder.itemView.id_txt.text = currentItem.idI.toString()
    holder.itemView.type_et.text = currentItem.type
    holder.itemView.rue_et.text = currentItem.nomRue

    holder.itemView.rowLayout1.setOnClickListener{
        val action = 
ListFragmentImmeubleDirections.actionListFragmentImmeubleToUpdateFragmentImmeuble(currentItem)
        holder.itemView.findNavController().navigate(action)
    }

}
fun setData (immeuble: List<Immeuble>){
    this.immeubleList = immeuble
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
}
```

and here is my custom_row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="24sp"
android:id="@+id/rowLayout1">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id_txt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="1"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/type_et"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
    android:text="Immoblier"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/id_txt"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rue_et"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:text="Boulevard X"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/type_et"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and here is fragment_list_immeuble.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".fragments.list.ListFragmentImmeuble">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:tint="@color/white"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I spent hours trying to find out what's wrong.. I'd be pleased if anybody could help!

Comment: How many items are there in list ?

Comment: Move your code from `onCreateView` to `onViewCreated`. You shouldn't access UI inside `onCreateView`, view inflation is an asynchronous task and inside `onCreateView` you're not sure view is inflated completely yet.

Comment: Make the height and width of the Recycleview to 0dp, it constraint with all sides
Also write the code in onViewCreated as suggested by @YaMiN

Comment: View creation is not done asynchronously. `onCreateView` and `onViewCreated` are both called on the main thread, as is view inflation. This could not be the source of the problem. Most likely cause is your list only has one item unexpectedly so I’d use the debugger to rule that out. Also check that your item layout isn’t filling the whole screen with one item.

Comment: Thank you guys for the useful tips, I tried most of them but in the end I found out that i'm not auto generating the primary key (can't get any dumb), therefore only 1 item was inserted and displayed in the recyclerview. Thread can be closed!